# How do I re-direct my Tumblr custom domain to a directory?

Tags: redirect, dns, tumblr

I have set up a custom domain on Tumblr. It is working fine. xxxxxx.tumblr.com redirects to xxxxxx.com. But I would really like that xxxxxx.com redirects to xxxxxx.com/tagged/xxxxxxx

A example that works:

langleav.tumblr.com --> langleav.com --> langleav.com/tagged/popular

I have a domain from Name.

thanks in advance

- Usually I would modify the htaccess file. But I can't use that in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect in your example is done client-side with JavaScript.

When you deactivate JS and visit `langleav.tumblr.com`, you get a server-side redirect to `langleav.com`.

When you activate JS and visit `langleav.tumblr.com`, you get a server-side redirect to `langleav.com` and then a client-side redirect to `langleav.com/tagged/popular`.

There are various ways to redirect client-side. See for example this question: [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/1591669)